# Nextjs automatic deployment to a cpanel using github actions

Tags: github, deployment, next.js, cpanel, web-deployment

I have successfully deployed a static html, css site to my "Bluehost" cPanel using GitHub actions, when I tried to deploy my Next.js app I failed, during the first try I get a plain web page with index and the folders of my projects after doing some research I have tried to upload the build folder to the FTP and it gave me the same error.

The plain web page after uploading the build folder files:

[image]

Anyway I know that I'm doing it the wrong way. All I'm asking for is the best automated way to deploy my Next.js app to the cPanel using GitHub actions or any other automated tools.

Comment: You need to export your app before uploading it with FTP. [`next build && next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export)

Comment: That's what I did, and I get the plan page with folders you can check the image uploaded in the question

Comment: You have uploaded `.next` directory. You need to upload the `out` directory.

Comment: That's all no need to create a starter server.js file??